# Alternative to updating every row in my table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, update

My syntax below works (may not be the most efficient syntax, but it almost serves the purpose).  The issue that I have with it, is that when the `UPDATE` statement is run, due to the `JOIN` condition each row that fits the criteria is updated.  I would like to only `UPDATE` 1 row, per `empName`.  Maybe I could use the field `AcctIDWorked` to update either the `MAX()` or the `MIN()` of this field?  Doesn't matter either way honestly as I just need **ONE** row per `empName` updated.

How can I accomplish this?

DDL Below and current syntax

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.__SalesDetailInfo', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.__SalesDetailInfo; 

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.__Sales', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.__Sales; 

Create Table __Sales
(
    EmpName varchar(max)
    ,TotalSaleAmount decimal(10,2)
)

Insert Into __Sales (EmpName, TotalSaleAmount) Values
('OWT', '167.30'),('Fit D', '512.22'),('Mike',  '4147.60')
,('Curtis', '66.96'),('Curtis', '1165.58'),('Curtis',   '1507.64')
,('Curtis', '1551.79'),('Curtis',   '8132.13'),('Curtis',   '28.62')
,('Sam',    '499.00'),('Curtis',    '1159.76'),('Sam',  '2011.98')
,('Mike',   '450.00'),('Mike',  '1453.60'),('Sam',  '762.45')
,('Curtis', '1056.00'),('Mike', '1596.50'),('OWT',  '1768.80')
,('Mike',   '1200.00'),('Mike', '1500.00'),('Fit D',    '17921.30')
,('Curtis', '456.73'),('Curtis',    '944.23'),('Curtis',    '2242.00')
,('Mike',   '437.50'),('Sam',   '3258.07'),('Sam',  '3258.07')
,('OWT',    '7263.57'),('OWT',  '7225.57'),('OWT',  '224.63')
,('Curtis', '569.89')

Create Table __SalesDetailInfo
(
    EmpName varchar(max)
    ,TotalSales decimal(10,2)
    ,AcctIDWorked int
)

Insert Into __SalesDetailInfo (EmpName, AcctIDWorked) Values
('Curtis', 1), ('Curtis', 2), ('Curtis', 3), ('Curtis', 4)
,('Fit D', 22), ('Fit D', 11), ('Fit D', 44)
,('Mike', 110), ('Mike', 111), ('Mike', 113), ('Mike', 114)
,('Sam', 300), ('Sam', 310), ('Sam', 340)
,('OWT', 500), ('OWT', 550), ('OWT', 580), ('OWT', 590)

;WITH UPDATECTE AS
(Select EmpName, sumTSA=SUM(TotalSaleAmount)
FROM __Sales
GROUP BY EmpName)
UPDATE __SalesDetailInfo
SET TotalSales = sumTSA
FROM UPDATECTE cte
  INNER JOIN __SalesDetailInfo t
    ON RTRIM(LTRIM(cte.EmpName)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(t.EmpName))
```

Comment: Why are you storing redundant aggregate information in *any* row in this table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I am trying to uncover how to update only 1 row - which would alleviate the storing redundant aggregate info, correct?

Comment: By redundant I mean you can always calculate the SUM when you need it. Why store information that you have to keep updated constantly in order to be accurate, every time any row is updated?

Comment: Very valid point.  Would the query be more efficient like this (I have not tested this syntax, but should get the point across as to what I was thinking of setting up)   ---- `Select
sdi.empName
,TotalSalesAmount = COALESCE((Select SUM(s,TotalSalesAmount) 
      FROM __Sales s where 
      Where s.empName = sdi.empName),0)
FROM __SalesDetailInfo sdi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.*, s.sumTSA
from __SalesDetailInfo t
join ( Select EmpName, sumTSA = SUM(TotalSaleAmount)
       FROM __Sales
       GROUP BY EmpName
     ) as s
ON RTRIM(LTRIM(s.EmpName)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(t.EmpName))
```

You could use that to create a view.